# Ionic Framework responsive table with data attribute not working as expected

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to achieve a responsive table for mobile using ionic framework. I am using the example from [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPVNW) (codepen) as of the codes below too

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Issue Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Period</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Payment">Payment #1</td>
            <td data-label="Issue Date">02/01/2015</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$2,311</td>
            <td data-label="Period">01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Payment">Payment #2</td>
            <td data-label="Issue Date">03/01/2015</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$3,211</td>
            <td data-label="Period">02/01/2015 - 02/28/2015</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {   
    font-family: arial;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}

table th, table td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

table th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    table {
        border: 0;
    }

    table thead {
        display: none;
    }

    table tr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    }

    table td {
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 13px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }

    table td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }

    table td:before {
        content: attr(data-label);
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

I have tested this example previously using Onsen Hybrid Framework and also on a normal website, when the max-width of the browser or the mobile screen is below 600px, it will should be as the picture below

[image]

but what really happened with mine when using ionicframework is as below which are not aligned as it should be

[image]

The code used is exactly the same for both pictures with the codepen link given above. Am I missing something here which made it like this?

Note: If ever there is an alternative to this problem, i don't mind converting if it works.

Comment: in ionic css, try to delete table,tr,th and td styling

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Actually, I have tried not even including Ionic CSS and still it is not working

Comment: i try your code with ionic, and dont have any problem with that. check your whole code again

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira, okay ill try it again.